# How to convert an angular velocity vector over a time period to a quaternion?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, quaternions

I am confused about how to convert axis angles to a quaternion. In my case i want to convert an angular velocity vector to a quaternion.

How can i convert an angular velocity vector over a time period to a quaternion using Eigen?

Why do I get different results with different methods? I don't get it :)

Edit: Obviously i don't get something here, isn't an angular velocity vector multiplied with a time an angle vector that can be transformed to a quaternion?

Using the angles xyz = [1 2 3] as input i get different results.

Matlab:

```
q = angle2quat(1,2,3, 'XYZ')
output(wxyz): -0.3689    0.7549   -0.2061    0.5015
```

Eigen:

```
  auto q = AngleAxisd(1.0, Vector3d::UnitX())
                     * AngleAxisd(2.0, Vector3d::UnitY())
                     * AngleAxisd(3.0, Vector3d::UnitZ());

  output (wxyz): -0.368871 0.754934 -0.206149 0.501509
```

Online approach https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/how-do-i-apply-an-angular-velocity-vector3-to-a-unit-quaternion-orientation :

```
   auto delta = 1.0;
   auto VectorType angularVelocity(1,2,3);
   auto norm = angularVelocity.norm();
   auto normt = norm * delta / 2.0;
   auto w = cos(normt);
   auto v = angularVelocity / norm * sin(normt);
   return QuaternionType(w, v.x(), v.y(), v.z());

   output(wxyz):  -0.295551 0.255322 0.510644 0.765966
```

Online converter https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/ "Axis with angle magnitude (radians)":

```
output (wxyz): -0.2955511, 0.2553219, 0.5106437, 0.7659656
```

Comment: `angle2quat` in matlab is convertion from Euler Angles to quaternion. Which is what you have demonstrated by showing that it is product of three rotation matrices. Aside from that, I find your question strange. Angular velocity vector isn't convertible to quaternion as Angular velocity isn't a rotation. Did you mean rotation it will produce over some time duration? That's what you got from the bottom half's calculations.

Comment: Yes, i meant angular velocity over a time duration as quaternion. 

I have to admit i still can't wrap my head around quaternions, but i was wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish this with Eigen than the online approach.

Comment: You can create (via construction or assigning) an `Eigen::Quaterniond` directly from `Eigen::AngleAxisd(angularVelocity.norm() * delta, angularVelocity.normalized())`

Comment: @chtz ty that actually works